# Some help understanding columnIndex in ViewBInder

Tags: android, android-viewbinder

**Skip to the bottom if you just want to see the question without context**

The android app I'm building has a simple table with three columns:

> **_id** INTEGER PRIMARY KEY..., **name** TEXT, **color** INT

This table is called `categories`.  I load my categories from the database and feed them into a `SimpleCursorAdapter` for use with a `Spinner` like so:

```
String[] from = new String[] {
        ListDbAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME,
        ListDbAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY_COLOR };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.categorySpinnerItem };

mCategorySpinnerAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    R.layout.category_spinner_item, categoryCursor, from, to);

mCategorySpinnerAdapter
    .setViewBinder(new CategorySpinnerViewBinder());
mCategorySpinner.setAdapter(mCategorySpinnerAdapter);
```

I set a custom `ViewBinder` because I want the category name to be the text of the spinner item, and the color to be the background color.  My `ViewBinder` looks like this:

```
private static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
private static final int COLOR_COLUMN = 2;

@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) view;

    String name = cursor.getString(NAME_COLUMN);
    int color = cursor.getInt(COLOR_COLUMN);

    textView.setText(name);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return true;
}
```

**Here is my question (finally)**

In the *setViewValue* method, what is *columnIndex* supposed to be doing?  The documentation says *"the column at which the data can be found in the cursor"* but when I debug through *setViewValue* I hit it three times and *columnIndex* is always `1`.

I was expecting the debugger to get into *setViewValue* once for each entry in the from array, with a columnIndex first of `1` and then `2`.  Or maybe once for each column in the query results.

The above code works, I can get the desired functionality but only because of my NAME_COLUMN and COLOR_COLUMN constants.  I'd be really interested to hear an explanation of *setViewValue* and its parameters from someone more experienced with custom ViewBinders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source of SimpleCursorAdapter, the `setViewValue` is called in `bindView` :

```
bound = binder.setViewValue(v, cursor, from[i]);
```

where the third param **from[i]**, which is the interesting one, is an iteration over an **int[]**, which represents the column indexes used. However the index for **[i]** for the iteration itself comes from the **int[] to** which is passed to the constructor of the adapter, and in your case, it has only 1 item - **R.id.categorySpinnerItem**

EDIT: In two words, the String[] and the int[] should be equivalent, same size and in same order - for each column name you need an int R.id... first view id will be connected to the first column id with from[0], second with from[1] and so on, and if you pass 10 columns, but you have only 3 R.id-s, you will get only to from[2] :)

Comment: Excellent idea, I hadn't thought about looking at the source before.  And what you point out is very interesting.  I suppose then, that the only time columnIndex is useful is when you have multiple views in your to array.  Or... is this saying that my to array should have as many values as my from array, even if it would mean the same value multiple times (to = new int[] { R.id.categorySpinnerItem,  R.id.categorySpinnerItem})?  I will have to play with this a bit more tomorrow.

Comment: now I remember that it WAS that way, which actually is the only way that makes sense, but I have forgotten this :) So you have to change your code, you can't manipulate 1 view with 2 columns (one for name and one for color)

Comment: @binary lobster - it means that column #1 will set the text for textView #1, #2 for #2 and so on

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confused because you missed the part with the return value - true if you bind the data, false otherwise (*and the adapter attempts to handle the binding on its own*). I think that the idea is like with the `OnTouchEvent`- giving you the option to consume it or not. So, you are always returning true at index 1, and you are never offered the index 2, because you have binded the view already, that's the only explanation I can think of about having always only 1 in the columnIndex param.

However, I almost haven't used cursor adapters - I find them not-OO, it is way better to create a POJO somewhere else, initializing it however you want using the db columns, and when you have a shaped list of objects just sending them to a "normal" adapter, it sounds more MVC. For example, if at some point you decide that `KEY_CATEGORY_NAME` will be in the format "cat_name##cat_description" (for example) you have to change the `Adapter`. Sounds more reasonable to change your class Category, so the getName() will return just "cat_name", and the adapter is the same.

So, because I almost haven't used `CursorAdapters` , if I am right about the columnIndex, please **DO tell me about it**, because I am curious but I don't want to create a CursorAdapter and check it myself :)

Comment: Dang I really wanted this to be the answer!  But, in my tests, regardless of whether I return true or false I always come back into the method with 1 as the columnIndex.  I even went so far as to return false EVERY time but the results didn't change.  My view text and color were still set and columnIndex never changed!

Comment: Hey, check out the source for SimpleCursorAdapter, it's all there, I will write it as a new answer, so I can markup the code, and it would be longer than a comment probably